# Create Hive Table with hyphen (-) in Table Name

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I need to create a table in Hive (v-1.2.2) with hyphen (-) in table name.

Reading Hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable), I tried to round table name with backticks (`) and it fails.

**Query Executed**

`` CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `kpisample_MarkContent_db786910-bd59-11e7-8329-9f28c9dd3095` STORED AS AVRO LOCATION '/prod/kpisample/dataset=0c253b00-2f04-11e6-ae13-d90f2a2beea0/KPI_id=MarkContent/year=2019/month=11/day=18/hour=4/' TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/prod/schemas/kpisample/dataset=0c253b00-2f04-11e6-ae13-d90f2a2beea0/KPI_id=MarkContent/kpisetting_MarkContent.avsc'); ``

**Fail Message**

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [kpisample_MarkContent_db786910-bd59-11e7-8329-9f28c9dd3095]: is not a valid table name`

Is there any way to do so?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try double quotes.

Comment: Tried and not worked. `FAILED: ParseException line 1:22 cannot recognize input near '"kpisample_MarkContent_db786910-bd59-11e7-8329-9f28c9dd3095"' 'STORED' 'AS' in table name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, table name containing `-` is not legitimate.
The source code taken from `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils` shows that only **characters**, **numbers** and **underscores** are allowed in table names:

```java
/**
   * validateName
   *
   * Checks the name conforms to our standars which are: "[a-zA-z_0-9]+". checks
   * this is just characters and numbers and _
   * ...
   */
  static public boolean validateName(String name) {
    Pattern tpat = Pattern.compile("[\\w_]+");
    Matcher m = tpat.matcher(name);
    if (m.matches()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```